How to open a Windows store app (UWP app) from the command line
If I list all app installed from PowerShell (Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, PackageFullName), I get a big list. Is trere any way to run from command prompt or powershell those apps, just to see what they are.
For example, I want to start (from cmd or powershell or run dialog only) "Microsoft.Windows.PeopleExperienceHost" or "Microsoft.ZuneMusic"

UWP cannot be started from the command prompt nor PowerShell

General Command to Open a UWP App
You can open the apps with the command:
Start-Process "shell:AppsFolder\<PackageFamilyName>!<Application Id>"

Quick Solution
Here is a function to open UWP apps by their name value. If the application has multiple IDs, it attempts all of them. You can list out the names with the command Get-AppxPackage | Select Name. Then, create the function in your PowerShell session with the command below.
Function Open-UwpApp($PackageName) {
    $PackageFamilyName = (Get-AppxPackage -Name $PackageName).PackageFamilyName
    $ApplicationIds = ( Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package ( (Get-AppxPackage -Name $PackageName).PackageFullName ) ).Package.Applications.Application.Id
    $AUMIDs = @()
    ForEach ( $ApplicationId in $ApplicationIds ) {
        $AUMIDs += ( $PackageFamilyName + '!' + $ApplicationId )
    }
    ForEach ( $AUMID in $AUMIDs ) {
        Start-Process "Shell:AppsFolder\$AUMID"
    }
}

After that, you can open the app with the command Open-UwpApp "<PackageName>".
Example: Open-UwpApp "Microsoft.WindowsStore"

Simple Solution for Applications in the Start Menu
Using the command Get-StartApps that Destroy666 provided in his answer, you can quickly get the AUMID from all applications in the Start Menu. You may wish to output it as a list to ensure the whole values are visible. The AppID property is the AUMID and can be used to open the app. It also lists the AUMIDs for non-UWP apps.

List applications in the Start Menu formatted as a list.

Get-StartApps | Format-List


Open an app using the AppID property.

Start-Process "Shell:AppsFolder\<AppID>"


General Steps to Open an Applicaiton with its AUMID
[1]: Get the PackageFamilyName property from the Get-AppxPackage command.
[2]: Get the Application Id from a property using the Get-AppxPackageManifest command.
[3]: Run the command (substitute the correct values): Start-Process "Shell:AppsFolder\<PackageFamilyName>!<Application Id>"

[1]: Get the <PackageFamilyName>

Use the command Get-AppxPackage | Select Name to find the application's  value. Use the following command to get the PackageFamilyName, which is the first part of the AUMID. Additionally, include the PackageFullName, which can be used in Step [2] to get the Application Id.

Get-AppxPackage "<PackageName>" | Select PackageFamilyName, PackageFullName | Format-List


Example <PackageName>: Microsoft.WindowsStore
Example <PackageFamilyName>: Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe
Example <PackageFullName>: Microsoft.WindowsStore_22409.1401.5.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe


[2]: Get the <Application Id>

Use the <PackageFullName> to find the <Application Id>.

( Get-AppxPackageManifest -Package '<PackageFullName>' ).Package.Applications.Application.Id


Example : App StoreDesktopExtension
This package has 2 Application Ids. App and StoreDesktopExtension. I'm uncertain if the first will always work, so you may potentially need to try the subsequent value(s).


[3]: Open the App
Start-Process "Shell:AppsFolder\<PackageFamilyName>!<Application Id>"

Which, in this example, translates to the following:
Start-Process "Shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"


Also note, you can open the app using the Run command as well. Simply remove "Start-Process" from the command. The quotes are only needed if a space is in the path, which doesn't seem to happen in these paths.

Shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App


Further Information About AUMIDs
Destroy666's answer provided further insight into the <PackageFamilyName>!<Application Id> portion of the command, which is known as the AUMID (Application User Model Id). He provided a link to Microsoft documentation detailing how to Find the Application User Model ID of an installed app. He also cited the Get-StartApps command which provides AUMIDs for apps in the start menu. The documentation he provided also has functions to get the AUMID of all installed applications. This method doesn't involve going into the AppxManifest.xml like my original solution. So, I've updated my answer to use the Get-AppxPackageManifest command to get the Application Id. The documentation he provided also has a function to list AUMIDs for all installed applications. Very helpful!

There's also a bit simplier way with help of Get-StartApps that returns the whole AUMID in AppID property. For example:
(Get-StartApps | ? { $_.AppID -like "Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe*" }).AppID | % { Start-Process "shell:appsFolder\$_" }

where Microsoft.ZuneMusic_8wekyb3d8bbwe is the PackageFamilyName from Get-AppxPackage.
Note: the drawback is that this will attempt to launch all apps related to the family, if there are multiple, which might occur with certain apps. You could also look by exact display name if you know it, it's unconveniently not part of Get-AppxPackage though and likewise Get-StartApps provides only those 2 properties. Just adding this answer as a point of interest in case Microsoft improves what the functions return, as of now acmctr's answer is more reliable.
